# Python convert string to table

Tags: python

My python program return this output:

['102000\tAdkins\tDavon\t2019\tFall\tMBA']

I want the output to be like this:
[image]

How to format the string or other ways to make it like this table.

Comment: 1) It looks like your variable is a list with a single string entry. It that what you intended?
2) If so, what do you get when you add the command print(variable[0]) where variable is the name of your variable? 
3) Obviously you need to add a print statement to print the column labels first.

Comment: Is your desired output an image? HTML? CSV? Console output? Lots of ways, but you haven't specified.

Comment: Should be console output

Comment: What output is it ? As everyone asking you, Is it CSV , console or HTML ? Please be specific, especially in this platform.

Comment: Can you provide your code here,  we can definitely help you with that!

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string at the "\t"s via string.split() and then create a dict with the column names as keys and apply the values.
Sadly there isn't a native table type in Python, which has columns and rows so you have to use this workaround.

If you want to add more to the columns just put the values in lists and apply those to the dict.

The end result could look like this:

```
{
  "ID": ["102000"],
  "LastName":["Adkins"],
  ...
}
```

w3schools has some handy articles about the techiques used:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp